# Kendo UI grid ClientTemplate ternary condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am trying to add a condition in ClientTemplate method in Kendo UI. The If else statement works fine, but when trying to use ternary operator HTMl does not render.

Working code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("marketWatchGrid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.direction).ClientTemplate("# if(Clients==''){ # - #}else{# #: Clients # #}#")
        })
    );
```

Not working:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("marketWatchGrid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.direction).ClientTemplate("# Clients=='' ? '-' : #: Clients # #")
        })
    );
```

Using htmlEncode

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("marketWatchGrid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.Clients).ClientTemplate("# (Clients=='' ? '-' : kendo.htmlEncode(Clients) ) #")
        })
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using ternary operator:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("marketWatchGrid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.Clients).ClientTemplate("#: Clients=='' ? '-' : Clients #")
        })
    );
```